# Swift Package Manager - How to use it

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a project that I want to use [this package](https://github.com/SwiftGL/Math) in my app. I googled and follow the instructions:

```
//in Terminal

? mkdir SGLMath
? cd SGLMath
? swift package init --type executable
```

Then I open the `package.swift` file and change to this:

```
// swift-tools-version:3.1

import PackageDescription

    let package = Package(
        name: "SGLMath",
        dependencies: [
            .Package(url: "https://github.com/SwiftGL/Math.git", majorVersion: 1)
        ]
    )
```

then `Terminal`:

```
? swift package fetch
```

Then I got this error:

> error: the package has an unsupported layout, unexpected source
>   file(s) found:
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/EqualWithAccuracy.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/FunctionsTests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/Matrix2x2Tests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/Matrix3x3Tests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/Matrix4x4Tests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/SwizzleTests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/Vector2Tests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/Vector4Tests.swift,
>   /Users/xuanxi/SGLMath/.build/checkouts/Math.git-9167533630816302265/Tests/glmMatrixTests.swift
>
> fix: move the file(s) inside a module

How can I resolve this?

2. What if I want to add this package into my existing `Xcode` project?

Answer (score 1):

1. The project https://github.com/SwiftGL/Math.git does not have the correct Swift Package Manager format. The files in `Tests` directory should be in a directory with name: the module name + "Tests" ending appended, in this case `SGLMathTests`. You can fork the project and fix it or ask the author to fix it.
2. To use the project with Xcode, once you fix it:

   a. Run `swift package generate-xcodeproj`. It will generate an Xcode project with the package.

   b. Create an Xcode workspace and add to it your existing Xcode project and the generated project in the previous step. Add the framework with the package from the generated project to your existing Xcode project as a dependency. This should work.